# List Comprehension Nested Loop, Multiple Operations

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given a list like so:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I'm trying to get my output to look like this, with using only a list comprehension:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Right now I have this:

```
[print(x,end="") for row in myList for x in row]
```

This only outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Is there a way to have it break to a new line after it processes each inner list?

Comment: If you're not building a list, why are you trying to use a list comprehension?  Why not a set or dictionary comprehension, if we're building dummy objects only to discard them?

Comment: `print()` is a function with side-effects, don't use it with comprehensions: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in mylist))
```

Gives:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do like the below.

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for i in l:
        print(' '.join(map(str, i)))


1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Why not `print(*i, sep=' ')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for line in l:
        print(*line)
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

A good explanation of the star in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/223486). tl;dr version: if `line` is `[1, 2, 3]`, `print(*line)` is equivalent to `print(1, 2, 3)`, which is distinct from `print(line)` which is `print([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ashwini Chaudhary that using list comprehension to print is probably never the "right thing to do".

Marcin's answer is probably the best one-liner and Andrew's wins for readability.

For the sake of answering the question that was asked...

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function # python2.x only
>>> list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [print(*x, sep=' ') for x in list]
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
[None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`print("\n".join([' '.join([str(val) for val in list]) for list in my_list]))`

```
In [1]:  my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [2]: print("\n".join([' '.join([str(val) for val in list]) for list in my_list]))

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```